# how to use bibitem instead of bitex in a thesis

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibitem

I have the references written as

```
\bibitem{wang}
Z.-Y. Wang, Y. -T. Gou, J. -X. Hou, L. -K. Cao, X.-H. Wang,  
Probabilistic Resumable Quantum Teleportation of a Two-Qubit 
Entangled State. Entropy , 21, 352 (2019).
```

and in the main document of my thesis  I use

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\usepackage[autosttyle=true]{csquotes}
```

it gives an error

I removed all usepackage related to biblatex and also \printbibliography~ ~just before end document in the main file. and I write the bibligraphy in the last chapter of my thesis, but I have the references written as [wang] instead of numerical format [1] when I use \cite{wang}.

Comment: You can't use `biblatex` with manual `\bibitem` entries:  are you perhaps wanting to simply do everything by hand?

Comment: yes I want to use bibitem

Comment: In this case, do not load `biblatex`

Comment: should i remove  all usepackage related to biblatex from the main file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format the bibliography -- contained in the environment `thebibliography` environment -- by hand, there's no role for the `biblatex` package.

Comment: I removed all usepackage related to biblatex and also \printbibliography~  ~just before end document. and i write the bibligraphy in the last chapter of my thesis, but I have the references written as [Bennet] instead of numerical format [1]

Comment: @soumia - Your comment is not straightforward to interpret, as you're not exactly providing a lot of usable information. In your initial posting, you describe a `\bibitem` with key `wang`. But in the comment, you mention something about an entry named `[Bennet]`. Please start by stating how the `wang` entry is formatted at present. Is there any connection between the wang and bennet entries? Do please show the `\bibitem` that generates `[Bennet]` instead of `[1]`. Please also state if you load a package such as `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: I removed all usepackage related to biblatex and also \printbibliography~ ~just before end document in the main file. and I write the bibligraphy in the last chapter of my thesis, but I have the references written as [wang] instead of numerical format [1] when I use \cite{wang}.

Comment: @soumia - I still have virtually no idea what you're actually doing, as opposed to being informed about the things you're *not* doing. Thus, do please reveal what exactly you're doing to generate a citation call-out of the form [wang]. Are all `\bibitem` entries embedded in a `thebibliography` environment? Please also confirm that your document does *not* load either the `cite` or the `natbib` package. Aside: Neither `cite` nor `natbib` are "related to `biblatex`".

Comment: yes all \bibitem entries embedded in a thebibliography environment. my document  does not load either the cite or the natbib package.

Comment: Thus, do please reveal what exactly you're doing to generate a citation call-out of the form [wang]?  for example in the Introduction chapter of my thesis I use \cite{wang}, also i write thebibliography environment in the last chapter of my thesis

Comment: @soumia `biblatex` will show the bold entry key if a citation is not found. All other BibTeX-based solutions that I know of show a question mark. So if you still get a bold "[wang]" from `\cite{wang}` it stands to reason that your document still somehow loads `biblatex`. Make sure that you have removed *all* references to `biblatex`. Check your preamble and also have a look at the files that might be included in your preamble.

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem i have just to delete the old main.aux file and reset.